# Apache won't start and there are no errors

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

Apache will not start. There are no errors in the journal. Where do I find further info?

```
$ systemctl status httpd.service -l
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-09-04 09:26:03 EDT; 2min 35s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2303 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2302 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2302 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
$ journalctl --dmesg
No journal files were found.
```

Answer (score 5):

`journalctl --dmesg` shows kernel error messages, not application error messages.

`journalctl -xe` may show more error messages.  For example, I added a bad line to my `httpd.conf` and now I can see

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Sep 04 09:39:04 server httpd[24802]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 
Sep 04 09:39:04 server httpd[24802]: Invalid command 'gibber', perh
Sep 04 09:39:04 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exit
Sep 04 09:39:04 server kill[24804]: kill: cannot find process ""
Sep 04 09:39:04 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process e
Sep 04 09:39:04 server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP 
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
```

Since this is `apache` you can also run `httpd -t` which will try and parse the config files and report on any mistakes.

```
% httpd -t      
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'gibber', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```